# "liblzma library and headers are required" when installing R-4.2.2 and dependencies under $HOME

Tags: r, redhat, lzma, xz

I am installing R-4.2.2 under my `$HOME` path on a Red Hat 4.8.5-28 server.

When I run `./configure --prefix=$HOME/R --enable-R-shlib` I found the error:

```
checking whether bzip2 support suffices... yes
checking for lzma_version_number in -llzma... no
configure: error: "liblzma library and headers are required"
```

I have install `xz-5.2.2`, and the headers and library have already been under `$HOME/local/include` and `$HOME/local/lib`. The path of the library has also been added to the `$C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I am not install them to the default path by ways like yum because I do not have the permission.

Comment: Perhaps this question would get more traction at serverfault.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used by the *dynamic linker* at *runtime*. The variable plays no role for compilation (and even for runtime configuration it has serious issues and is generally best avoided).

You would normally set `LDFLAGS` to include the appropriate library paths. However, this should be done *by the `configure` script*, not by you. Instead, you would pass the appropriate command line flags to the `configure` script (something like `--with-lzma=the/path`), or by configuring the [`PKG_CONFIG_PATH`](https://askubuntu.com/q/210210/9287).

The same is true for the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable, incidentally: setting it manually before invoking `./configure` is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I added the path of .pc files (`$HOME/local/lib/pkgconfig`) to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and finally `ld` can found the library of lzma. Yet it still dosent works for configuring R, so I revised the configure file and added the path of librarys and head files in `$HOME/local` to the configure file, then the installation of R finally succeeded.